# Angular 5 Runtime compiler is not loaded

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I am compiling my angular project using

```
ng build --prod
```

But I get

```
main.bundle.js:1 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Runtime compiler is not loaded
```

I can't figured out what to do.
This is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "gestionerADJ",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.0.0-beta.2",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^2.0.0-beta.8",
    "rxjs": "5.5.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.14"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^1.5.5",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~3.2.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~3.2.0",
    "tslint": "~5.7.0",
    "typescript": "~2.4.2"
  }
}
```

I have seen some other questions about this error but none of them is helping me.. Thank you to any of you that are going to help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have any modules inside your project you're not lazy-loading, you might want to switch to lazy-loading:

```
export const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: myComponent,
        children: [
            {
                path: '',
                loadChildren: myModule
            }
        ]
    }
];
```

Replace `loadChildren: myModule` with `loadChildren: '../../test.module#myModule'`, using the appropriate path for your project.

Comment: why? It's not make sense to let all module lazy-loading

Comment: This does not help with modules that cannot be lazy-loaded. I had to switch from lazy-loading after upgrade because if you try to lazy-load a module that is already loaded you will get other equally infuriating errors with equally unhelpful error messages.

Answer (score -1):

You make changes in `angular.json` under option in architect. Add lazy Modules like this:

```
"lazyModules": [""]
```